# Retaining spaces in decoding process

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I need to write a program that will take the encoded message, flip it around, remove any characters that are not a letter or a space, and output the hidden message.
Sample input:

```py
d89%l++5r19o7W *o=l645le9H
```

Expected output:

```
Hello World
```

My output:

```
HelloWorld
```

If I use a white space as separator, it returns

```py
H e l l o w o r l d
```

My code:

```
decode = [ch for ch in input() if ch.isalpha()]
print("".join(decode[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space character is not an alphanumeric character.

In your original code, use:

```py
decode = [ch for ch in input() if ch.isalpha() or ch == ' ']
```

instead.

---

If you want to retain other types of whitespace besides the space character (e.g. tabs, newlines), use:

```py
decode = [ch for ch in input() if ch.isalpha() or ch.isspace()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex approach:

```py
inp = "d89%l++5r19o7W *o=l645le9H"
output = re.sub(r'[^A-Z ]+', '', inp, flags=re.I)[::-1]
print(output)  # Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
inp = 'd89%l++5r19o7W *o=l645le9H'

decode = []

for i in inp[::-1].split():
    decode.append("".join([ch for ch in i if ch.isalpha()]))

print(" ".join(decode))
```